# Dot matrix printing in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to print in `Epson LX-300+ II` printer from `c#`. I want to increase the font size. I am using:

```
sw.Write((char)27);
sw.Write((char)69);
sw.Write((char)14);
```

to make the printout bold.

Is there any code to increase the font size?

Comment: `StreamWriter` is responsible to pass raw data (i.e. byte array). You need to read printer's API documentation to understand how it formats text so you could write desired buffer using `StreamWriter`.

Comment: ok tanx. but then how the bold is working in same way?

Comment: there is another method without using stream Writer. create a word template and fill the required data in particular cells of a table. Then its easy to set font, font size, bold for each cell. Then send the word file to the printer.

Comment: Great. You should post it as an answer so other readers could find solution easily.

Answer (score 0):

there is another method without using stream Writer. create a word template and fill the required data in particular cells of a table. Then its easy to set font, font size, bold for each cell. Then send the word file to the printer.